# What happened to the undergrad students who attended the Feynman Lecture Series in 1961-63?

Tags: physics, biographical-details

Note: This question was originally asked [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51681/what-happened-to-the-undergrad-students-who-attended-the-feynman-lecture-series), but I was wondering if I could get further clarification as this has truly intrigued me.

> In the academic years of 1962-2 and 1962-3, Richard Feynman gave his celebrated series of lectures to a cohort of undergraduate physics students at Caltech. ... The careers of all those students, now aged somewhere in their mid 70's, have all ended or are winding down. Has anyone done an analysis of performance, relative to expectations, of the careers of these fortunate students?

Comment: I might wonder why the "expectations" of these students would be any different from any other class year at CalTech.